# 200 wired with 110?

Tags: electrical

Background: My Dad passed a few years ago and I have hired several people to upgrade cabinets and lights in his 70's home.  Zip code 85001.  Come to find out, there is 220 attached to the 110 and apparently this is not a good thing.  Worse thing is that every electrician I have spoken to me will not touch my project.  One handyman told me that after a long search he could not find where the issue was.  Half the house now has power and half does not...I was told that there is a machine that can help track this issue but their are different grades of volt testers.  I would surely appreciate anyone that could point me in the right direction.  Please....

Comment: Welcome. Let's work on terminology a bit. If you're in the U.S., voltages have been 120/240 since the post-war era. Secondly, wiring isn't 120 or 240--it's based on current load, and it's referenced in wire size. The same wire size can accommodate _both_ 120 and 240v circuits. Please do what you can to verify your wire sizes and update your question with that detail, along with more information about your circuit layout. We can't help otherwise.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean by electricians "will not touch your project".   At face value it seems unlikely that an electrician would "not touch" the diagnosis and repair of an electrical problem.  What exactly did you ask them for and what did they say?

Comment: Multi-Wire Branch circuits are bog standard and can supply 240 and 120 from the same circuit, when desired. They are neither good nor bad. However, you may have a more fundamental issue like a lost phase if half the house does not have power. But far more details are required to get anything more than "well, that's odd, but you have not provided enough information to have a hope of helping you"

Comment: Yes, You are correct. The issue is 220V.   I'm lost and do not know electrical jargon. The handyman said it was looped with 110 but he could not trace where the issue was.  The local electricians that did come to talk either said they were not interested in bidding for the job or said yes but never returned or will not answer my calls or messages.

Comment: A picture of the inside of your breaker panel will help. But, don't open it yourself, you don't seem to have enough experience. Next time an electrician has it open, take some good pictures. Don't touch, keep a few feet away.

Comment: Learn the basic terminology: Here are a few sites to get you started: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/wiring-a-breaker-box/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring_in_North_America  https://ricardolevinsmorales.com/square-d-breaker-box-wiring-diagram/

Comment: Even a photo of the breaker panel with the door open so we can see the breakers may be helpful. If you can find out if all the outrages are on odd or even breakers that could tell us something also if the house has a sub panel the sub may have tripped causing an outage for the area the sub covers with more info we can help you figure things out.

Comment: @DebStew -- is there any pattern to which circuits in the house do or don't have power?

Comment: @DebStew -- also, does what works or not work change when you run the dryer or the range, or the air conditioner kicks in for that matter?

Comment: For troubleshooting jobs, you bid time + materials, not flat rate.  Cost can spiral if there are many problems so be prepared for that.  It can still be worth it to know what the problems are.  Higher than 120V where 120V should be could be caused by a broken neutral problem on a shared neutral circuit.

Comment: Hard to know what's going on here, but it sounds like you lost one "side" of the 240v service.  Yet any decent electrician should have known that immediately. Still, a call to the power company saying you lost power in half the house would result in a visit to check transformer connections and connections in the meter base. They don't charge for that.  It would be unusual for electricians not to want to touch something like this unless something really funky is going on.  Like others have said, send some pics of the breaker box (door open, cover still on) and meter base.  Best of luck.